# Unstable scaling on 2 displays with different resolutions

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

My main screen is a 17.3' laptop screen with UHD resolution (3840x2160) and my second display is 23' (1920x1080). My configuration is 2x scaling for the UHD display and 1x for the other one. The main screen's scaling works as expected. When opening any window on the secondary screen, everything is scaled to 2x. Windows automatically adjusts window sizes when moving them around, is it possible to do the same on Ubuntu? I am running Ubuntu 16.10 with GTX1070 and nvidia driver is version 367.57.

Comment: For now, the state of 4K on ubuntu is just grim. Scaling just refuses to work well across multiple monitors of multiple resolutions. I would highly recommend you just use 1080p on both displays until such time as Ubuntu gets its stuff together. Alternatively, you can give the [HiDPI instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI) on the Arch Wiki a try.

Comment: A year later and things are still woeful, constant crashes when connecting/disconnecting monitors, or adjusting any settings really. Almost unusably bad.